# Is it possible to use compiled Swift framework without Headers and Modules folders provided

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, reverse-engineering

Compiled Swift framework consists of **executable**, **_CodeSignature**, **Info.plist**, **Headers**, **Modules**. A framework built inside an iOS app only has **executable**, **_CodeSignature** and **Info.plist**. Is it possible by not having **Headers** and **Modules** part take any use out of a framework? Is it possible to somehow recreate headers and other necessary stuff from binary and if it is how practical is it?

Comment: It is doable for C/ObjC framework. For plain C framework you’d need to use a decompiler like Cutter. For ObjC framework, you could use classdump to get the headers. For swift framework, which is fundamentally modular, you’ll have to somehow replicate a swiftmodule. I am not aware of any tool that can generate a module with framework swift APIs out of a plain binary.